# filtering file according to the highest number in a column of each line

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIT01734 transcript:OIT01734 1.1e-107    389.8   1000    218 992 1   216 130 345 MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDAR*  MKVWERVVEARVREMTSISVNQFGFMPGRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEHFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLENAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFPVVMGLHQGSALSPLLFALVMDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDAPVRIYKSAILGHLNSHGSQNALAGPVEAEENRQKTKKEVMEEIIQKSKFFKAQKAKDREENDELTEQLDKDFTSLVESKALLSLTQPDKINALKALVNKNISVGNVKKDEVADVPRKASIGKEKPDTYEMLVSEMALDMRARPSDRTKTPEEIAQEEKERLELLEQEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDGNASDDNSKLVKDPRTVSGDDLGDDLEEVPRTKLGWIGEILRRKENELESEDAASSGDSDDGEDEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEEQGKTQTIKDWEQSDDDIIDTELEDDDEGFGDDAKKVVKIKDHKEENLSITVAAENKKKMQVFYGVLLQYFAVLANKKPLNSKLLNLLVKPLMEMSAVSPYFAAICARQRLQRTRAQFCEDLKNTGKSSWPSLKTIFLLRLWSMIFPCSDFRHCVMTPAILLMCEYLMRCTIISGRDIAIASFLCSLLLSVIKQSQKFCPEAIVFIQTLLMAALDRKQRSNSQLDNLMEIKELGPLLCIRSSKVEMDSLDFLTLMDLPEDSQYFHSDNYRTSMLVTVLETLQGFVNVYKELISFPEIFMLISKLLCKMAGENHIPDALREKIKDVSQLIDTKAQEHHMLRQPLKMRKKKPVPIRMLNPKFEENFVKGRDYDPDRERA    389.8   1000    216 85.6    185 31  200 0   0   92.6    0   22IV6AV2SN4IV11IL12GSDA1PS1GE3ED1MK4AV6VF9DE29IV1HQ6FY2MV5FL1EG10IV14CR1HL4KR1KR5QE5PL2KE2GR6FY6GR3 85.6    1.1e-107    99.1
gene.10002.1.1.p1   NisylKD957037g0001.1    NisylKD957037g0001.1    0.0e+00 1218.8  3152    668 780 5   667 122 780 KVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN KVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN MFGFKVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN*    MGAKRTRSNSESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALGSGFAQGPSLVAATSTIISTGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSSAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN    1218.8  3152    665 91.0    605 52  621 3   8   93.4    0   11HR12SNE-E-E-F-E-D-5GA24CR3EP14ED26RG5LH85GS4RGGD2ISHR2-P24HR70FL2MI7IV20IL8VA25DE5RG17RG4AP7KN10CY13FVAS6KT1ML16AT4SP13TK3QH12SP3RS36FL4FVSF6EG12VI6-EAV13LV3TS8LS2QR2PS3VI2TKVI2IL15IT19TS9  91.0    0.0e+00 99.3
gene.10002.1.4.p1   NisylKD957037g0001.1    NisylKD957037g0001.1    0.0e+00 1216.8  3147    671 780 9   670 123 780 VIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN  VIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN  MFGFKARIVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN* MGAKRTRSNSESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALGSGFAQGPSLVAATSTIISTGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSSAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN    1216.8  3147    664 91.0    604 52  620 3   8   93.4    0   10HR12SNE-E-E-F-E-D-5GA24CR3EP14ED26RG5LH85GS4RGGD2ISHR2-P24HR70FL2MI7IV20IL8VA25DE5RG17RG4AP7KN10CY13FVAS6KT1ML16AT4SP13TK3QH12SP3RS36FL4FVSF6EG12VI6-EAV13LV3TS8LS2QR2PS3VI2TKVI2IL15IT19TS9  91.0    0.0e+00 98.7
gene.10002.1.5.p1   NisylKD957037g0001.1    NisylKD957037g0001.1    0.0e+00 1218.8  3152    668 780 5   667 122 780 KVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN KVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN MFGFKVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN*    MGAKRTRSNSESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALGSGFAQGPSLVAATSTIISTGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSSAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN    1218.8  3152    665 91.0    605 52  621 3   8   93.4    0   11HR12SNE-E-E-F-E-D-5GA24CR3EP14ED26RG5LH85GS4RGGD2ISHR2-P24HR70FL2MI7IV20IL8VA25DE5RG17RG4AP7KN10CY13FVAS6KT1ML16AT4SP13TK3QH12SP3RS36FL4FVSF6EG12VI6-EAV13LV3TS8LS2QR2PS3VI2TKVI2IL15IT19TS9  91.0    0.0e+00 99.3
gene.10002.1.6.p1   NisylKD957037g0001.1    NisylKD957037g0001.1    0.0e+00 1440.2  3727    799 780 15  798 1   780 MGAKRTRSNGESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALESEFAQSPSQVAATSTIISIGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSIAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN    MGAKRTRSNSESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALGSGFAQGPSLVAATSTIISTGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSSAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN    MSDCTWQRYKGEVLMGAKRTRSNGESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALESEFAQSPSQVAATSTIISIGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSIAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELAHIPSLEEAPVFHPSEEEFEDTLKYVGSILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSCIEEESTVYGVNTHIQRTSELQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSRKSDFGLDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESGFPHERGVTIHRPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSHESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLFQNMAFQFSPSILTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLILPGAYHAHVDSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVDLYSEQRRKTSISYDKLLFEAATERIRALAELPLLHKKFFDNLKWRAVCRSNEILTKALKSRFATEVRRRKYMCASLESRKMEDDFCATAKRECSICYYDLYLSAIGCTCSPQKYTCLLHAKQLCSCAWREKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGFPVSDFSKDASKDEMKVKSESGQSLDVEQDRKEASIPSVGPSARTNNLNRVTGSWVEADGLSHQPQPKGIVNDTVEVIFPKISQHATVGKNIMISSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRTVIILSDDEN* MGAKRTRSNSESDDGYKLSVPPGFESLMSFTLKKVKNSEEACNSVALGSGFAQGPSLVAATSTIISTGKLKSSVRHRPWILDDHVDHIEDDSEFEDDKSLSSSAFLPKGVIRGCSSCHNCQKVIARCRPELARIPSLEEAPVFHPNTLKYVASILPHVKHYGICRIVPPSSWKPPSRIEEPSTVYGVNTHIQRTSDLQNLFFKKRLEGACTRTNNKQQKTLSGKSDFGHDIERKEFGCCNEHFEFENGPKLMLKYFKHYADHFKKQYFVKEDQITASEPSIQDIEGEYWRIIENPTEEIEVLQGTSAEIKATESSFPHEGDVTSRRPPQYVESGWNLNNTPKLQDSLLRFGSRESSSILLPRLSIGMCFSSNLWRIEEHHLYLLSYIHFGAPKIFYGVPGSYRCKFEEAVKKHLPQLSAHPCLLQNIAFQFSPSVLTSEGIPVYRCVQNPKEFVLLLPGAYHAHADSGFNCSEAVNFAPFDWLPHGQNAVELYSEQGRKTSISYDKLLFEAATEGIRALPELPLLHKNFFDNLKWRAVYRSNEILTKALKSRVSTEVRRRTYLCASLESRKMEDDFCATTKRECPICYYDLYLSAIGCKCSPHKYTCLLHAKQLCPCAWSEKYLLIRYEIDELNIMVEALDGKVSAVHKWAKEKLGLPVSDVFKDASKDGMKVKSESGQSLDIEQDRKEEVSIPSVGPSARTNNVNRVSGSWVEADGSSHRPQSKGIINDKIEVLFPKISQHATVGKNIMTSSNTVLKKHLARESSSTKRSVIILSDDEN    1440.2  3727    786 91.5    719 59  735 3   8   93.5    0   9GS37EG1EG3SG2QL9IT35IS29HR12SNE-E-E-F-E-D-5GA24CR3EP14ED26RG5LH85GS4RGGD2ISHR2-P24HR70FL2MI7IV20IL8VA25DE5RG17RG4AP7KN10CY13FVAS6KT1ML16AT4SP13TK3QH12SP3RS36FL4FVSF6EG12VI6-EAV13LV3TS8LS2QR2PS3VI2TKVI2IL15IT19TS9   91.5    0.0e+00 98.1
```

The above file has some IDs which are similar

```
gene.10002.1.1.p1
gene.10002.1.4.p1
gene.10002.1.5.p1
gene.10002.1.6.p1
```

By remaining only `gene.10002` the IDs become identically. I used this awk script (thank you to @anubhava ) to keep only lines of the same ID with smallest value (column 30)

```
awk '{
   if (/^gene\./) {
      split($1, a, /\./)
      k = a[1] "." a[2]
    }
    else
       k = $1
}
!(k in min) || $30 <= min[k] {
   if(!(k in min))
      ord[++n] = k
   else if (min[k] == $30) {
      print
      next
   }
   min[k] = $30
   rec[k] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[ord[i]]
}' file
```

I failed to modified the above awk script to consider the maximum value in column 31 and to keep multiple copies if the column 31 value is the same?

```
awk '{
   if (/^gene\./) {
      split($1, a, /\./)
      k = a[1] "." a[2]
    }
    else
       k = $1
}
!(k in max) || $31 <= max[k] {
   if(!(k in max))
      ord[++n] = k
   else if (max[k] == $31) {
      print
      next
   }
   cov[k] = $31
   rec[k] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[ord[i]]
}'
```

Comment: Is this a different question from the one at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/618989/133219

Comment: Yes, it is a different question, because this one looks for the highest value. On unix.stackexchange the question refers to remove identically hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing OP's attempt here, could you please try following. You should change your condition to do comparison for `>=` condition in `$31 >= max[k]`, since we are looking for maximum value now, added detailed explanation later section of this post too.

```
awk '{
   if (/^gene\./) {
      split($1, a, /\./)
      k = a[1] "." a[2]
    }
    else
       k = $1
}
!(k in max) || $31 >= max[k] {
   if(!(k in max))
      ord[++n] = k
   else if (max[k] == $31) {
      print
      next
   }
   max[k] = $31
   rec[k] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[ord[i]]
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '{                             ##Starting awk program from here.
   if (/^gene\./) {                ##Checking condition if line is NOT starting from gene. then do following.
      split($1, a, /\./)           ##Splitting first field into array a with delimiter dot here.  
      k = a[1] "." a[2]            ##Creating variable k with value of a[1] DOT a[2] here.
    }
    else                           ##In case line NOT starting from gene. then do following.
       k = $1                      ##Setting 1st field value to k here.
}
!(k in max) || $31 >= max[k] {     ##Checking condition if k is NOT in max array and 31st field is >= max[k]
   if(!(k in max))                 ##If above any of the condition is true then check if k is NOT present in max
      ord[++n] = k                 ##Creating ord with index of increasing value of n and its value is k
   else if (max[k] == $31) {       ##else printing maximum duplicate line, no need to keep appending it in array.
      print                        ##Printing it here.
      next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
   }
   max[k] = $31                    ##Creating max with index of k and value of 31st field.
   rec[k] = $0                     ##Creating rec with index of k and value of current line.
}
END {                              ##Starting END block of this program from here.
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)            ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of n here.
      print rec[ord[i]]            ##Printing array rec with index of; value of ord array which has i index.
}' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to work. However, do I need to convert the string value to integer by `$31+0`?

Comment: @user977828, Please see this difference `echo "abcd12234" | awk '{print $0+0}'` is 0 AND `echo "1234abcd12234" | awk '{print $0+0}'` is 1234 so if your 31st field starts from digits and you want to have initial digits then go ahead, else use sub function to remove all non numeric things and get only digits in that field.

Comment: @user977828, to get only digits in 31st field do something like `sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$31)` and you should be good with it.